# imagemagick increases size of image on conversion

Tags: imagemagick

I am using ImageMagick version (6.8.9). On converting the image from one format to another the file size seems to increase. I am not able to find out the exact treason for this. I used quality as well. Still i am not able to find a solution for this problem

Thanks in advance

Comment: More information needed. Converting between formats while preserving image sizes almost guarantees an image size change. As long as you understand why, and it makes sense, this isn't necessarily incorrect.

Comment: I tried converting a png and jpeg image to jxr format. But instead of reduction in size of image which was expected the size of the image increased. I tried changing the quality but found no difference

Comment: Can you please post the actual command you used?

Comment: convert inputfile.png -quality 80 output.jxr